# Thought on reducing snowflakes cost by dropping unused objects

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Part1 #
As per the pricing policy of snowflakes ,we will be paying based on the usage and we will not be charged if we won't use resources..This is clear.However I Am trying to understand ,is there any chance for reducing the cost  if we drop the unused or rarely used warehouses? users and roles that are not been used any more ?I was looking some cost savings  in terms of reducing the cloud services cost.

Part 2#
which is the  most cost effective way .

1)Allocating separate warehouse for each team who uses the warehouse at specific times 
    (or)
2)Allocating single warehouse for all them and monitor warehouse load  closely,such that if we notice queued load on warehouse then opt  scale out option(multi cluster)(S+S)?

Please suggest the best way so that we can reduce overall cost.

Comment: IMO It's always a good idea to drop unused objects to keep everything clean

Answer (score 1):

1. there are only two things major things you are charged for disk and cpu, and a couple of minor things like compile time, and inter region IO charges. But users, warehouses, & roles are just access control lists in the end, that are to control cpu and disk usage.
2. prior to per second billing we found using one warehouse for a couple of teams meant less wasted CPU billing, and to some degree that almost is the case with the min 60 second billing, but we have a shared x-small most teams do dev on, and then spin-up bigger warehouses to run one-off loads (and then shut down) or have auto-scaling clusters to handle "normal load" which we also use cron jobs to limit "max size" just so in the off-peek times we intentionally increase latency of total load, to shift expenditure budget to peek times. and compared to the always running clusters, our dev instances are single digit percentages, so 1 or 2 warehouses is a round error.

The way we found the most value for reducing cost, was to look at the bill and see what seemed more $$ then we expected for the bang we where getting, and then we experimented, to see if there were lower cost ways to reach the same end goal. Be it different shaped tables that we multi inserted into, or finding queries that had long execution times, or pruned lots of rows (which might lead to the first point).. if you are want to save dollars you have to whach/care how you are spending them, and make trade-offs.

Answer (score 0):

Part #1

Existence of multiple Warehouse will not incur any cost, cost will only come when it will be utilized as part of compute. However dropping unused objects will certainly ease the operational effort. Also if user exists and not being used it should fall under your security audit and it is always better to disable a user instead of dropping. Validate all downstream application ETL jobs/BI reports (If any) before dropping any users/roles

Cloud service cost is entirely different ball game , it follows 10% rule. One need to pay  this amount when cloud service usage exceeds 10% of the warehouse usage on that day.

Part #2

Snowflake always suggest warehouse should be created based on your activity. Please do not create warehouse to segregate teams/user group. Create user and roles for that.

What we observed

During development keeping only one virtual Warehouse, until real requirement pops up (Project team wise segregation for cost sharing or budgeting or credit assessment) there is no need to have multiple warehouse created.

Even for Prod activity wise segregation is ideal, one for ETL load/BI reporting / Data analytics team

Thanks

Palash Chatterjee